# Multiple Ajax Requests on one Rails View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two ajax requests on one page (one displaying a date, one displaying a calendar)

Request one : on click of a date (on the calendar), will update the date.

Request two : you can change between months of the calendar.

What happens is I have both functions in index.js.erb and it always executes both, resetting the date in 'request one' everytime I change months.

Can I make it so it only executes one function of index.js.erb at a time?

**Index.js.erb**

```
$("#calendar").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/calendar')) %>");
$("#today").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/today')) %>");
```

**_today.html.erb**

```
<div class="span3 offset2 dateToday">
    <% end %>
    <span id="currentdate">
        <%= @eventDate.strftime("%B") %><br>
        <span id="dayDate"><%= h @eventDate.day %></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**_calendar.html.erb**

```
  <h2 id="month">
      <span class="pull-left"><%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m-01") %></span>
      <%= h @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
      <span class="pull-right"><%= link_to ">", :month => (@date.end_of_month+1).strftime("%Y-%m-01") %></span>
  </h2>
  <%= calendar_for(@events, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month) do |t| %>
      <%= t.head('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun') %>
      <%= t.day(:day_method => :eventdate) do |date, events| %>
  <div class="day">
      <%= link_to(date.day,  {:day => date }, :remote => true, :class => "btn dayBtn") %>      
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**EDIT: routes.rb**

```
resources :calendar

root :to => "calendar#index"

match '/faq',   to: 'calendar#faq'
match ':controller/:action'
```

**EDIT - link to ajax action**

```
<%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m-01"), :action => "update_calendar", :remote => true %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are either going to have to set up logic to respond differntly based on some params you pass along, or you need to break these out into two differnt actions, because they really are two differnt actions.

So something like this if you use the param approach.

```
-if param[:one]
  $("#calendar").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/calendar')) %>");
-if param[:two]
  $("#today").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/today')) %>");
```

Or as said before just break them up into different actions.

In your controller

```
def update_today
 #your today logic thats in your current action
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js{render}
 end
end

def update_calendar
 #your today logic thats in your current action
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js{render}
 end
end
```

You would then have to add routes for these two actions.

update_today.js.erb

`$("#today").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/today')) %>");`

update_calendar.js.erb

`$("#calendar").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/calendar')) %>");`

Comment: how do I break them into two actions?

Comment: Create method in your controller update_today and update_calendar and have them each just do the logic for one of the updates.

Comment: do you think you could elaborate? I am a total novice.

Comment: I'm running into a routing error. I want to pass in the month variable when I click the "update_calendar" action, but its routing it to /calendar/update_calendar/2013-02-01 instead of /calendar?month=2013-02-01. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your Routes file in your question so I can help.

Comment: I added routes and my ajax action to see if that helps

Comment: Can you access the stored date at params[:month] inside the controller? If not put the following in your controller "puts params.to_s" and post the results from the log.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27301/discussion-between-steven-ritchie-and-rovermicrover)

Comment: I managed to solve it using an if statement (like you suggested) but instead of passing rails params in the IF statement, I used a variable in application.js to identify where the click came from. :)

Comment: I was always unsure what the best practice was for routing AJAX requests. I was using the param approach and felt my controllers were getting too cluttered and my AJAX requests were running lots of unnecessary code. I'm going to begin separating my AJAX requests and routing them to their own actions. I wish there was more clarity on this somewhere on the Internet. I scoured many guides, blogs, questions, etc. for it and this is the only time I've seen the issue actually raised. Many thanks to the OP and to rover.